# angular : $scope is not reading values from HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this code where I am expecting some data from the View/HTML but the variable $scope.cityName is undefined.

```
app.controller("citycontroller", function ($scope, cityfactory) {
        $scope.searchByCid = function () {
            console.log("Checking for city data");
            var promise = cityfactory.serverCall($scope.cityName);
            promise.then(function (data) {
                $scope.result = data.data;
                console.log($scope.result);
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.error = error;
            });
        };
        console.log($scope.cityName);
    });
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="cityName" placeholder="Search places.." ng-init="cityName='Delhi'">
            <button ng-click="searchByCid()" id="checkcity">Check</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: is `$scope.result` data correct in your console ?

Answer (score 1):

`console.log($scope.cityName);`

This statement is not part of any change event handler or function that digestion cycle to cause run.

Your `cityName` is changing.If you want check it in JS :

```
$scope.callMe = function(){
   console.log($scope.cityName);
}
```

HTML :

Use [`ngChange`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cityName" placeholder="Search places.." ng-init="cityName='Delhi'" ng-change="callMe()">
```

OR Simply check in html using `interploation`:

```
<span>{{cityName}} </span>
```

OR

use [`$scope.$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) in JS.

```
$scope.$watch('cityName',function(oldVal,newVal){

    console.log(newVal); //it will print new updated cityname
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object in your controller instead of using a single variable `$scope.cityName`. Try to use something like `$scope.data.cityName`, changing your `ng-model` to `data.cityName`. Also, try to initialize your variable in the beginning of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
 console.log($scope.cityName);
```

This statement is outside the  $scope.searchByCid function. When controller get loaded first time(While rendering html) then it is calling

```
console.log($scope.cityName);
```

Because of that it is showing undefined for $scope.cityName;

But you will be getting $scope.cityName in $scope.searchByCid because it is initialized using ng-init attribute.

Shift console.log inside your method.